# Localizing parameter label in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

is there a possibility to localize parameter prompt name?

Anyway, is there possibility to even change prompt name beside that in parameters settings?

Comment: Do you have a resource assembly containing globalization labels? If so, you can include that in your SSRS project and access the resource lables via code.

Comment: I have separated resource files, and in reports i have reference on _.dll_ file which deal with that _.resx_ files. So, What I want to tell is that on reports I just calling method from referenced _.dll_ file, and that excellent works with fields on report body, but I don't have a way to resource parameters prompt name.

Comment: I agree with GShenanigan. I thought the parameter promt could be set with an expression and I was wrong. It seems the prompts can only be set at design time. Without modifying the .rdl file there is no way to do this is seems.

Comment: Is there a possibility to dynamically change XML of _.rdl_ file during runtime, somehow to pull in XML and based on app language translate the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid this isn't possible directly in SSRS.

However, you can create your own web/windows application in .NET with localised controls/labels and use the ReportViewer control to embed the SSRS report.

You can then use the SSRS Web Service to interact with the report object on the server, discover the required parameters, and create your own parameter area in your application.

- [Details on how to access the Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337423%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [ReportViewer control documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)